# dplyr mutate new column according to the value of existing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to add a new column based on the values of two existing columns.

My data set looks like this:

```
    V1   V2  V3
1   1    I
2   2    C
3   1    C
4   1    A
5   2    C
...
```

The new column V3 should follow the following condition:
'''

```
if (V1==2 & V2==C) {
V3 <- 1
} else { V3 <- 0
}
```

'''

However, when I tried to create the column, I got the following error:
'''"Evaluation error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types."'''

Ideally, the result should be like this:

```
   V1  V2  V3
1   1   I   0
2   2   C   1
3   1   C   0
4   1   A   0
5   2   C   1
...
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your data is a `tibble` or `data.frame` but you can run `str(data)` to see if there are no lists in there. If it is a simple data frame then this should work:

```
> data <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,1,1,2), V2 = c("I", "C","C","A","C"))

> data%>%mutate(
   V3 = ifelse(V1 %in% 2 & V2 %in% 'C', 1, 0)
 )

  V1 V2 V3
1  1  I  0
2  2  C  1
3  1  C  0
4  1  A  0
5  2  C  1
```